# Multi lingual react application with JSON.JS (as backend)

Tags: reactjs, json, multilingual, translate

I developed a web application and it is a dynamic site. Can I place a multilingual option for my site? I go further to develop a multilingual application? I have got through many provided solution with i18next but thats the solution for static data.

I have reusable components with props. When I map through the data imported from JSON, I can't handle and apply i18next (static key concept). Is there any solution please.

For more details, here is the scenario,

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import ObjectiveCard from './ObjectiveCard';
// import objectiveData from '../../../../assets/resume_eng.json'; 
// import objectiveData from '../../../../assets/resume_dk.json';
import axios from 'axios';

const Objective = () => {

    const [objective, setObjective] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:9000/objective')
            .then(response => setObjective(response.data))
    }, [])   

    return (
        <div>
                {objective && objective.map((o, index) => {
                    return(
                        <ObjectiveCard
                            key={index}
                            myName={o.name}
                            jobTitle={o.jobTitle}
                            objective={o.objective}
                        />
                    )
                })}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Objective;
```

and child component is,

```
const ObjectiveCard = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1> {props.myName} </h1>
            <h3> {props.jobTitle} </h3>
            <p>
               {props.objective}
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default ObjectiveCard;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Community, I have updated my query and I hope now it will be more clear. Thanks